# How to use the shared thumbnail repository?

Tags: linux, thumbnails

[Freedesktop.org](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/thumbnail-spec/thumbnail-spec-latest.html#SHARED) states that .sh_thumbnails folder is used for shared thumbnails so  that a thumbnail is only generated once for mutually used files. I copied my thumbnails to that folder in a USB drive and altered those images so that I know the shared thumbnails are used but it generated thumbnails again and didn't use the ones I put in the .sh_thumbnails.

Note: I cleaned the thumbnail cache in advance. I tried using Thunar and PCManfm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xfce's `tumbler` thumbnailing component does not implement this part of the specification, and neither does pcmanfm (in libfm). And neither does libgnome-desktop, which is used by Nautilus in GNOME.

In fact according to [Debian Code Search](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=.sh_thumbnails&literal=1) there are only two apps which *do* implement the shared thumbnail directory at all.

(Considering that even the thumbnail-spec authors missed this section in v0.8.0 when updating for the XDG Base Directory specification…)

You might be able to achieve a similar result by mounting an `overlay` filesystem over your regular thumbnail directory, specifying it as both the mountpoint and the upper directory and the "shared" location as the lower directory.

```
sudo mount -t overlay overlay ~/.local/share/thumbnails -o upper=$HOME/.local/share/thumbnails,lower=$HOME/.sh_thumbnails,workdir=$HOME/.cache/thumbnails_overlay_workdir
```